# React router browser history with server routing

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router

I am writing a web application using `react` for client side and `express` for server side.
I am using `react-router` ([link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router)) routing the client pages.
Working with the `hashHistory` it was simple and worked fine, but now I want to use `browserHistory`.

As mentioned in the `react-router` tutorial, I need to tell my server to expect the client request, so when we render a client page it will server the `index.html`.
I can't find a way to handle both requests from the client for pages and requests for server processing.

For example, I have a page in the path `/product`, but I also have an endpoint for the server processing `/authenticate`.

In the `react-router` tutorial it says to use the following:

```
// server.js
// ...
// add path.join here
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// ...
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  // and drop 'public' in the middle of here
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

But this way will result every request (including `/authenticate`) to send it back to the `index.html`. How can I merge those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the `/authenticate` before the `*` (which is basically a Catch-All and has to come last)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

ap.get('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200)
});

// ...
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  // and drop 'public' in the middle of here
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```